# How to use PHP db2_bind_param with LIMIT and OFFSET in SELECT for DB2

Tags: php, db2

How do you pass LIMIT and OFFSET in a select statement values in PHP?

This code sample is based on the PHP handbook, DB2 examples.  It uses the animals database build in the db2_execute example:

```
$conn = db2_connect($database,$user,$passwd);
if ($conn) {
  $sql = "select * from ANIMALS order by BREED " .
        "LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
  $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
  if ($stmt) {
$the_limit = 3;
$the_offset = 2;
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "the_limit", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "the_offset", DB2_PARAM_IN);
    $result = db2_execute($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
      echo "level 2 exec error: " .db2_stmt_error($stmt) . "
      errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
    }
    while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
       echo $row['BREED'] . '  ' . $row['NAME'] . '  ' . $row
         ['WEIGHT'] . "\n";  
    }
} else {
      echo "level 1 exec error: " .db2_stmt_error($stmt) . " errormsg: " . 
         db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}
db2_close($conn);
} else {
   echo "connect error ".db2_conn_error() . " failed ".db2_conn_errormsg();
}
```

This example results in a 07006 error code, that is described as "An input variable, transition variable, or parameter marker cannot be used,
because of its data type."

PHP is running on an IBM I System (AS400), Zend Server 8.5.  The OS is version 7, release 1. PHP is 5.6.10.  IBM DB2 module is 1.9.7.

LIMIT and OFFSET are at least partially support because changing the statement to ... LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2 works as expected.

Comment: Please update the question to show your DB2 version +fixpack and operating-system platform. Also what is your version of the ibm_db2 component?  That's because it works fine for me if I use your code sample adjusted for my test databases, with DB2 Version 11.1.2.2 on Linux and PHP 7.0.22.   I believe the LIMIT and OFFSET syntax variants were made available in V11.1, because they don't appear in the documentation of V10.5 for LUW.

Comment: I am using DB2 on iOS400, Version 7, Rel 1.  PHP is 5.6.10, module release of the IBM DB2 drivers is 1.9.7.   Making limit and offset part of the query, eg. LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2, works as expected.  Thank you.

Comment: You can edit your question to include those details, it helps others who might answer you to have the information in the question instead of comments.     The version of the php extension "ibm_db2" that I am using is 1.9.9 which is the current release version at today's date.  Try updating that component. If it still fails for you, it must be a platform-specific issue (DB2 for i ) with ibm_db2, because it works fine for DB2 for Linux.  Worst case is you can dynamically create the SQL string with constants instead of parameter-markers. Verify the DB2-client  it is at latest fix level.